# Does the silver axe break in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Does the silver axe break in Animal Crossing New Leaf? I don't know if the silver axe breaks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Yes. The silver axe can eventually break.

Comment: You need more descriptive evidence. Where did you get the answer from?

Answer (score 9):

The silver axe has 136 hits of durability in New Leaf. Yes it breaks.

[Source](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Axe)

Comment: Is there a specific reason the number 136 was chosen?

Comment: @Miguel So it's more durable than the default axe(4.25x more durable), but not unbreakable like the gold. The silver Axe is easier to obtain in New leaf compared to other titles, so making it unbreakable like before would be too unbalanced.

Comment: It would have been nice if they had picked a number divisible by 3.

Comment: @Brian why would that matter?

Comment: @Rapitor A tree takes 3 hits to chop down.

Comment: Am unsure how [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/172957/30879) posted just over 3 hours later than this one got accepted when this one says how many it would take to break and even cite's it's source, this answer is clearly more useful to the poster and the better one

Answer (score 0):

That 137 is horribly, horribly wrong, I counted them myself with repeated silver axes I got off Club Tortimer, they're not even close to 100, try about 35 times to break, which is the same as the regular axe, the only thing that makes it different is that 100% of the time you get a rare stump.